Moving cppzmq message_t to background thread
I have a receiver thread. I want to move the messages into a queue for background processors threads. To put it simply:
std::queue<zmq::message_t> qu;
zmq::message_t msg;
zmq::recv_result_t res = sock.recv(msg, zmq::recv_flags::none);
qu.push(std::move(message));

I get an error:
include/zmq.hpp:745:5: note: declared here
  745 |     message_t(const message_t &) ZMQ_DELETED_FUNCTION;

Even without std::move, it's still not working.
I understand that zmq::message_t are not supposed to be moved like that. What is the correct way of doing that (efficiently, without un needed copying)?
I would expect that message_t will hold the message data allocated on the heap, and that will be freed in the destructor of the message_t. In that case, I don't understand what is the issue here.

Shan't be the code in an MCVE fashion, i.e. both C-omplete and V-erifiable ( so reproducible to run elsewhere ) ? ZeroMQ documentation ( working w ZeroMQ since v.2.0 ) was always explicit on how to touch message payloads, designed for zero-copy, low-latency, high-scalability performance, so do not mind to rather post the whole ecosystem setup in an MCVE fashion. That is the StackOverflow as I know it for the last decade. Shortcuts ( instead of going to use an MCVE ) are mostly longer, less comfortable and more expensive, than keeping the SOP to post an MCVE.

You could use
qu.emplace(std::move(message))

instead, or explicitly call move():
qu.push(message_t{});
message.move(qu.back());


Can you explain the reason behind this?
the second method is not suitable for threads, because I use the queue with a condition variable (so, like a blocking queue)

push might fall back to the copy constructor, depending on the underlying storage container. emplace constructs the new message in-place from an rvalue ref.
